# Problem with open files in Atom, VS Code only working in Python IDLE

Tags: python, ide, atom-editor

My Problem:
I want to work with a file called bestand.csv. So I have written some code to open the file:

```
bestand = open("bestand.csv")
```

When I want to run the code in Atom then I get this message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "A:\Drive\Fahrzeugverwaltung\Fahrzeugverwaltung.py", line 1, in 
 <module>
 bestand = open("bestand.csv")
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bestand.csv'
 [Finished in 0.098s]
```

Looks like there is no file called bestand.csv in the same directory. But the file exist.

[image: Files in the folder]

The same problem is in VS-Code 
The file does not appear to be found.

But when I run the code in Python IDLE I can open the file and can work with it.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Wondering if it's a path issue. Have you tried with the full path?

Comment: Provide the absolute path to the file to `open`: `open('A:/some-dir/bestand.csv')`

Comment: Now I have tried your method:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Drive\Fahrzeugverwaltung\Fahrzeugverwaltung.py", line 1, in <module>
    bestand = open("A:\Drive\Fahrzeugverwaltung\bestand.csv")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'A:\\Drive\\Fahrzeugverwaltung\x08estand.csv'
[Finished in 0.088s]`

Comment: It is easier to use forward slashes even for Windows paths. No backslash escaping needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple as thought: The problem here is that the path of the script was not read correctly into the IDE. Simply open the script from the folder with -> Atom and it works and the files are loaded correctly.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix could be automatically building an absolute path by where your script is located

```
import os

path  = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "bestand.csv")
bestand = open(path)
```